# Why is tuning svm algorithm using singular values (SVDs) extremely slow?

Tags: svm, svd, quanteda, e1071

I have a large data of more than 300,000 variables and about 5000 rows. By applying singular value decomposition using RSpectra, I retreived 300 singular values. Running svm with hyperparameter tuning by using these 300 variables has become incredibly slow.  It took more than 17 hours with a 24GB RAM machine. This algorithm worked much faster when I run it with a document feature matrix(dfm) of 60,000 variables and 5000 rows.

```
library(doMC)
start_time <- Sys.time()
registerDoMC(cores=5) 
library(e1071)
set.seed(123) #for reproducibility

svm_tuned_upsample <- tune(svm, 
                           train.x = train_svd_df[,-1], 
                           train.y = as.factor(train_svd_df$Include), 
                           kernel = "radial", 
                           type   = "C-classification", 
                           parallel= TRUE, 
                           ranges=list(cost=c(0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 15), 
                                       gamma=c(0.0009, 0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.0035, 0.004, 0.0045, 0.005)),
                           validation.x=tune.control(sampling = "cross",cross=10)
                          ) 

Sys.time() - start_time
```

Comment: a dfm is sparse, whereas the data.frame has 300bn values. Do you really need the radial kernel? Most text classification works best with a linear SVM. Try `quanteda.textmodels::textmodel_svmlin()`, it's extremely fast and works on sparse dfms.

Comment: Thanks, Ken, for your helpful response. Yes, it is it is really sparse and massive. Do I have to simply go with ```dfm_trim``` or try dimensionality reduction methods?  I tried linear, sigmoid and radial kernels and the prediction performance was better with radial. Yes, I used quanteda.text models SVM and it is lightning fast.  But, I used a different function. ```textmodel_svm() ```. Are they similar? I am using ```quanteda.textmodels``` version 0.9.1.